# iTunes "Show Artwork" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: itunes, shortcut

Does one exist? Can one be made? I've tried adding variations of "Show Artwork" to Syst Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts / App Shortcuts / iTunes, to naught.

The default operation to toggle view of the album-artwork column in iTunes is:

- Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to hail the columns control palette;
- Click the "Show Artwork" tickbox;
- Dismiss the palette with <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> again.

macOS Sierra, iTunes 12

Comment: You mean like a global shortcut that toggles album cover no matter what app is active?

Comment: I mean one that would toggle view of the album artwork column in iTunes (as can be done by the default operation above).